# How do I deserialize this type of data structure

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

This is my JSON:

```
"Dt": {    
    "20171021": {    
      "abc": "-"    
    },    
    "20171022": {    
      "abc": "-"    
    },    
    "20171023": {    
      "abc": "-"    
    },    
    "20171024": {    
      "abc": "-"    
    },    
    "20171025": {    
      "abc": "-"    
    }
}
```

The properties inside Dt is all dynamic. They are all dates but in string format. So I am thinking if I would need a List object but how would JSON.Net map this into List? I am thinking of class structure something similar to:

```
public class Dt
{
    public List<RealDate> RealDates { get; set;}
}

public class RealDate
{
    public string Date{ get; set;} //to hold "20171021"

    public Tuple<string, string> Keys {get; set;} // to hold abc as Key1 and - as Key2
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you able to influence the structure of this JSON? It would probably make more sense as an array containing a series of objects, each of which have "date" and "abc" as a property. Then the structure will be predictable, and you can deserialise it to a List easily. If you have to stick to the existing structure you could possibly try deserialising it to a Dictionary, off the top of my head

Comment: that's a invalid json ... see http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: @Rahul true, although I'm going to guess it's actually a snippet of a bigger object perhaps...it can be made valid by simply adding a set of outer brackets, of course

Comment: @ADyson may be and for sure posted json more looks like a dictionary but that's just a speculation and you don't know for sure

Comment: @Rahul I realise that...hence comment and not answer...was trying to prompt OP to confirm the details.

Comment: @ADyson make sense .. agree

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That look like there is no `Dt`, and the thing that currently *has* a `Dt` should actually have:

```
public Dictionary<string, Foo> Dt { get; set;}
```

where `Foo` is:

```
class Foo {
    public string abc {get;set}
}
```

You would then post-process this to turn the DTO model (the serialization model) into your *actual* model.

Remember: any time that there is even a minor difference between what the serialized data looks like, and what your domain model looks like: add a DTO model, and just map between them manually. It'll save your sanity.

Answer (score 1):

Your json is invalid (brackets are missing), but the following json

```
{
    "Dt": {
        "20171021": {
            "abc": "-"
        },
        "20171022": {
            "abc": "-"
        },
        "20171023": {
            "abc": "-"
        },
        "20171024": {
            "abc": "-"
        },
        "20171025": {
            "abc": "-"
        }
    }
}
```

Can be deserialized into the following objects:

```
public class Model
{
    [JsonProperty("Dt")]
    public Dictionary<string, Value> Data { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    [JsonProperty("abc")]
    public string Abc { get; set; }
}
```

Testing the code:

```
string json = @"{
    ""Dt"": {    
    ""20171021"": {    
      ""abc"": ""-""    
    },    
    ""20171022"": {    
      ""abc"": ""-""    
    },    
    ""20171023"": {    
      ""abc"": ""-""    
    },    
    ""20171024"": {    
      ""abc"": ""-""    
    },    
    ""20171025"": {    
      ""abc"": ""-""    
    }
}
}";

var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(json);
```